# Why do I get the following output when inverting bits in a byte?

Tags: c#, .net, endianness

*Assumption:*

> Converting a
>   byte[] from Little Endian to Big
>   Endian means inverting the order of the bits in
>   each byte of the byte[].

Assuming this is correct, I tried the following to understand this:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 24 };
byte[] inverted = ToBig(data);

var little = new BitArray(data);
var big = new BitArray(inverted);

int i = 1;

foreach (bool b in little)
{
    Console.Write(b ? "1" : "0");
    if (i == 8)
    {
        i = 0;
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    i++;
}

Console.WriteLine();

i = 1;

foreach (bool b in big)
{
    Console.Write(b ? "1" : "0");
    if (i == 8)
    {
        i = 0;
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    i++;
}

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data));
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ToBig(data)));

foreach (byte b in data)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", b);
}

Console.WriteLine();

foreach (byte b in inverted)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", b);
}
```

The convert method:

```
private static byte[] ToBig(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] inverted = new byte[data.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        var bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { data[i] });
        var invertedBits = new BitArray(bits.Count);

        int x = 0;

        for (int p = bits.Count - 1; p >= 0; p--)
        {
            invertedBits[x] = bits[p];
            x++;
        }

        invertedBits.CopyTo(inverted, i);
    }

    return inverted;
}
```

The output of this little application is different from what I expected:

```
00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 00000101 00001111 00011000

00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 00000101 00001111 00011000 

80-40-C0-20-A0-F0-18

01-02-03-04-05-0F-18

1 2 3 4 5 15 24 

1 2 3 4 5 15 24
```

For some reason the data remains the same, unless printed using BitConverter.

What am I not understanding?

**Update**

New code produces the following output:

```
10000000 01000000 11000000 00100000 10100000 11110000 00011000 

00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 00000101 00001111 00011000 

01-02-03-04-05-0F-18

80-40-C0-20-A0-F0-18

1 2 3 4 5 15 24 

128 64 192 32 160 240 24
```

But as I have been told now, my method is incorrect anyway because I should invert the bytes
and not the bits?

This hardware developer I'm working with told me to invert the bits because he cannot read the data.

**Context where I'm using this**

The application that will use this does not really work with numbers.

I'm supposed to save a stream of bits to file where

1 = white and 0 = black.

They represent pixels of a bitmap 256x64.

byte 0 to byte 31 represents the first row of pixels
byte 32 to byte 63 the second row of pixels.

I have code that outputs these bits... but the developer is telling
me they are in the wrong order... He says the bytes are fine but the bits are not.

So I'm left confused :p

Comment: FYI, endianess refers to order of bytes in a word, not bits in a byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method may be correct at this point.  There are different meanings of endianness, and it depends on the hardware.

Typically, it's used for converting between computing platforms.  Most CPU vendors (now) use the same bit ordering, but different byte ordering, for different chipsets.  This means, that, if you are passing a 2-byte int from one system to another, you leave the bits alone, but swap bytes 1 and 2, ie:

```
int somenumber -> byte[2]: somenumber[high],somenumber[low] ->  
byte[2]: somenumber[low],somenumber[high] -> int newNumber
```

However, this isn't always true.  Some hardware still uses inverted BIT ordering, so what you have may be correct.  You'll need to either trust your hardware dev. or look into it further.

I recommend reading up on this on Wikipedia - always a great source of info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

---

Your ToBig method has a bug.

At the end:

```
 invertedBits.CopyTo(data, i);
}

return data;
```

You need to change that to:

```
byte[] newData = new byte[data.Length];
invertedBits.CopyTo(newData, i);
}
return newData;
```

You're resetting your input data, so you're receiving both arrays inverted.  The problem is that arrays are reference types, so you can modify the original data.

Comment: Ok so this works better, but I'm doing it wrong anyway beecause I have to invert the bytes instead of the bits?

Comment: That is correct.  The order of the bytes needs to be switched, the order of the bits should remain the same.

Comment: I just tested it - your current code works (1st & 3rd prints), but with one exception:

The ToString() methods aren't giving what you expect because they're converting the byte[] reference itself, not the contents of the array, to a string.

Comment: James - True and False - your assumption is only true if the hardware has the same bit ordering as the CPU he's working from.  I'm not sure what hardware he's using, but sometimes you need to swap bits, not just bytes.

Comment: Reedcopsey, you may be absolutely correct. The hardware is being developed in CHina and I have no idea what CPU they are using. It is very difficult to communicate with the developer, but I think you may have clarified things !!!

Answer (score 6):

No. Endianness refers to the order of **bytes**, not bits. Big endian systems store the most-significant byte first and little-endian systems store the least-significant first. The bits within a byte remain in the same order.

Your ToBig() function is returning the original data rather than the bit-swapped data, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

As greyfade already said, endianness is not about bit ordering.

The reason that your code doesn't do what you expect, is that the ToBig method changes the array that you send to it. That means that after calling the method the array is inverted, and `data` and `inverted` are just two references pointing to the same array.

Here's a corrected version of the method.

```
private static byte[] ToBig(byte[] data) {
   byte[] result = new byte[data.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
      var bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { data[i] });
      var invertedBits = new BitArray(bits.Count);
      int x = 0;
      for (int p = bits.Count - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
         invertedBits[x] = bits[p];
         x++;
      }
      invertedBits.CopyTo(result, i);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Edit:
Here's a method that changes endianness for a byte array:

```
static byte[] ConvertEndianness(byte[] data, int wordSize) {
    if (data.Length % wordSize != 0) throw new ArgumentException("The data length does not divide into an even number of words.");
    byte[] result = new byte[data.Length];
    int offset = wordSize - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
        result[i + offset] = data[i];
        offset -= 2;
        if (offset < -wordSize) {
            offset += wordSize * 2;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
byte[] data = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
byte[] inverted = ConvertEndianness(data, 2);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(inverted));
```

Output:

```
02-01-04-03-06-05
```

The second parameter is the word size. As endianness is the ordering of bytes in a word, you have to specify how large the words are.

Edit 2:
Here is a more efficient method for reversing the bits:

```
static byte[] ReverseBits(byte[] data) {
    byte[] result = new byte[data.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
        int b = data[i];
        int r = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            r <<= 1;
            r |= b & 1;
            b >>= 1;
        }
        result[i] = (byte)r;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One big problem I see is ToBig changes the contents of the `data[]` array that is passed to it.

You're calling ToBig on an array named `data`, then assigning the result to `inverted`, but since you didn't create a new array inside ToBig, you modified both arrays, then you proceed to treat the arrays `data` and `inverted` as different when in reality they are not.